# Edits under 6 characters should be allowed if in a hyperlink URL

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, suggested-edits

The 'under 6 characters' limit on suggested edits should be waived for edits in URLs -- it should be possible to correct something like a trailing slash without messing with the prose.

Comment: Correct a trailing slash? How does that make any difference in the URL?

Comment: @mmyers There's no strict reason that `http://example.com/test` has to serve the same content as `http://example.com/test/`. They're different URLs. Most sites tend to cope gracefully with both, either correcting one to the other (usually adding a trailing slash) or serving the same content, but they don't *have* to, and some don't. A real-world example: http://uniquesentence.com/sentence/browse works, http://uniquesentence.com/sentence/browse/ is a 404. (I must get round to fixing that!)

Comment: Same problem when fixing a syntax error in a code example: Original poster writes a one-character syntax error. Sometimes it is besides the point to discuss this error and I just want to fix it. The six-character rule should trigger a warning, rather than blocking my edit.

Comment: @Philippe: Agreed.  If you want to encourage people to make more substantive edits, a warning would do that. The current rule *prohibits* people from making helpful edits.

Comment: I agree per my Q http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126099/cant-fix-link-in-answer-because-it-needs-minimum-chars-to-edit#comment341207_126099

Answer (score 1):

For example post [How to run a specific NUnit test from code using NUnit 3 (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578848/how-to-run-a-specific-nunit-test-from-code-using-nunit-3-c/35585901#35585901)

The maintainers moved the uri from ../dev/.. to ../doc/.. for example and the edit failed with the 6 char requirement.

This means the edit has to be 'coerced'.